# Android MediaCodec - Interpreting YUV420SP buffer via JNI

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, android-mediacodec, yuv

I am decoding an MP4 h.264 video using Android's `MediaCodec` class, extracting each `ByteBuffer` and attempting to convert to RGB so we can use it elsewhere.

After recieving a valid buffer index from `dequeueOutputBuffer()` and grabbing that `ByteBuffer`, we're using `GetDirectBufferAddress()` from the JNI to grab that buffer in the C code so we can do the conversion on that side. But for some reason the buffers were looking at don't seem to make sense when we look at the size values and byte layout we're getting back.

The MediaFormat I'm being given is apparently `COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar` according to the last time `dequeueOutputBuffer()` returned `MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED` - the full MediaFormat string follows.

```
VideoDecoder: decoder output format changed: {image-data=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=80,capacity=80], mime=video/raw, crop-top=0, crop-right=1279, slice-height=720, color-format=21, height=720, width=1280, what=1869968451, crop-bottom=719, crop-left=0, stride=1280}
```

The video's dimensions are 1280*720, and in YUV420SP we'd be expecting 12 bits-per-pixel - from which we calculate an expected buffer size as being 1382400 bytes. However when we retrieve the buffer from `GetDirectBufferAddress()` the size as returned from `GetDirectBufferCapacity()` is 1433600.

The other thing that looks odd is the byte placement within that buffer. When we're (supposedly) looking at a frame of a single colour, we see three distinct blocks of Y, U and V values - rather than the distinct block of Y, then a block of alternating values for U and V. From what MediaFormat is telling us, this doesn't make sense.

Can anyone tell us where our maths is going wrong? or is it the way we're retrieving the values? Or is there something about the buffer or colour format we're overlooking?

EDIT: We are targetting API Level 19. The Device used when debugging our code is an Google Nexus 7 by Asus, running Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

The general description of what you're trying to do sounds correct.

I wouldn't worry so much about the size of the buffer; this might be some overallocated buffer.

What android device is this, have you tried another one? Any Android device on 4.3 or newer should behave correctly with respect to this (older ones are notoriously broken with color format values basically being plain wrong, or requiring quirks in interpreting the YUV data), since there's a CTS test that enforces correct behaviour. This test is also linked from http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/; [EncodeDecodeTest.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeDecodeTest.java) is the relevant one.

If you get that code hooked up so you can run it standalone, you can see whether the test succeeds on your device and use that as reference to find out what's wrong in your code, or conclude that the device isn't to be trusted (and you can either ignore it and require 4.3 as minimum, or add a device specific workaround for it).